# Chrome Extension selected text

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to add a frame/border (like Evernote Web Clipper: below image) around my selected text into my Chrome extension.

[image]

To do that, I thought capture the HTML code of the selection and add a frame/border around the current selected text. But I don't see how can I do that...

Here is my code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
 "name": "Selected Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Selected Text",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "online.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["popup.js"]
   }
 ]
}
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
    }, function(selection) {

      console.log(selection[0]);
      if(selection[0].length > 0){
        document.getElementById("text").value = selection[0];
      }
});
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { width: 300px; }
      textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text"> </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the use of text area in popup.html?

Comment: @sabithpocker It's just to have a temporary preview.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `mouseup` event like this:

```js
// Add event listener for mouseup (there is no event for selection)
document.addEventListener('mouseup', highlightSelectedBlock, false)

function highlightSelectedBlock () {
  // TODO Filter only selections

  // Get Node where selection starts
  let elementWhereSelectionStart = window.getSelection().anchorNode

  // TODO Get Node where selection ends with Selection.focusNode()
  // TODO Get Nodes in between start and end of selection

  // I've hardcoded finding closest block element for a simplicity
  let closestBlockElement = elementWhereSelectionStart.parentNode

  // Add non disturbing border to selected elements
  // For simplicity I've adding outline only for the start element
  closestBlockElement.style.outline = '1px solid blue'
  
  // TODO Clear outline on some event: saving selection, ending selection etc
  setTimeout(() => { closestBlockElement.style.outline = 'none' }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<p>First line
<p>Second line
<p>Third line
```

But for real life it should be more complex, think of:

- selections from keyboard
- highlight several elements, which can be tricky
- selection of images inside
- removing highlight on a lot of different cases

Maybe it can be a good idea to constantly poll DOM for a selection object with [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of adding event listener to `mouseup`.